# Tem como fazer upload pra uma subpasta usando FileField?

Tags: django, file-upload

Quando eu defino um `FileField` (ou `ImageField`), tenho de especificar um `upload_to`:

```
campo1 = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads")
campo2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="img/%Y/%m/%d")
```

No primeiro caso, todos os arquivos vão pra pasta "uploads". No segundo, eles vão pra uma pasta diferente segundo o ano/mês/dia em que o upload aconteceu. Em ambos os casos, a pasta é predefinida.

Eu gostaria entretanto de fazer um upload pra uma **subpasta** daquela especificada em `upload_to`. Por exemplo:

```
subpasta = request.POST("subpasta") # Ex.: foo/bar
arq = request.FILEs("arquivo")      # Ex.: baz.txt

meuModelo.campo1 = ... # Resultado esperado: MEDIA_ROOT/uploads/foo/bar/baz.txt
```

É possível fazer isso com o `FileField` do Django? Ou - ainda que não dê pra *salvar* o arquivo dessa forma - alternativamente pegar um arquivo que *já está* numa subpasta de `upload_to` e simplesmente fazer com que o modelo "aponte" pra ele?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando uma função no `upload_to` é possível alterar o caminho/referência do arquivo, exemplo:

```
def upload_path_handler(instance, filename):
    return "uploads/%s/%s" % (instance.subpasta, filename)

class Arquivo(models.Model):
    arquivo = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_path_handler)
```

Referência: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload%5Fto

Comment: `instance` seria uma instância do modelo? Em que momento esse método é chamado, é quando se atribui o arquivo, quando o modelo é salvo... Um exemplo de uso e/ou referência pra uma documentação ajudaria bastante, se tiver algum. Idealmente, gostaria de fazer isso sem ter que criar um campo `subpasta` no modelo, apenas usar um parâmetro externo, tal como exemplificado na pergunta. Mas se não tiver jeito, acrescento uma coluna extra e faço dessa forma, fazer o que...

Comment: `instance` é a instância do modelo sim, com isso você poderia salvar por exemplo os arquivos dentro de um diretório com o `id` do usuário. Esse exemplo só vai ser incluído na documentação na próxima versão do Django, já é possível visualizar nesse link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload%5Fto

Comment: Em relação a subpasta você vai ter que criar uma coluna, porque ele sempre vai acessar o nome dessa subpasta dinamicamente.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou aqui (Django 1.4). Só um detalhe que não está explícito na documentação: o caminho retornado precisa ser **relativo**, i.e. *não pode* começar com barra (ex.: `/uploads/...`). Do contrário, será lançada uma `SuspiciousFileOperation` e consequentemente um "Bad Request (400)". Mais informações [nessa resposta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28124066/520779).

Answer (score 1):

O mais incrível do upload_to é que você pode definir uma função dentro dele, e com essa função validar ou fazer o que quiser. Te ajudando assim, no que precisaria. Neste exemplo, estou renomeando a imagem:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=rename_upload_image)

def rename_upload_image(instance, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
        return os.path.join('images/', filename)
```

Espero que te ajude